# GIMP slows down my Ubuntu 14.04 over time

Tags: ubuntu, memory, performance, gimp

I have some problems with my GIMP recently. When I start GIMP it runs perfectly fine, but over time, say about 15 minutes, it's starting to slow down my Ubuntu (14.04). After checking my system resources I figured out that GIMP is not using much CPU as I initially thought, but rather uses up all the RAM (90% or more). After closing GIMP, the RAM usage drops significantly and the computer speed regenerates. I'm not sure why this is, maybe because I copy-paste a lot and it saves the copied images in the RAM temporarily. Now to my questions:

Does anyone else have this problem, know what the actual problem is or know how to fix it? (e.g. allowing GIMP to use not more than 50% of my RAM)

Comment: Additional information about my problem: It seems that GIMP is saving something each second (cursor blinking) and each second the memory increases by approximately 10 MB. Hence it's not a problem due to copy-paste, but rather to saving too much data in the background.

Comment: Have you updated GIMP or OS recently?

Comment: @gronostaj: No, I haven't updated GIMP or OS, but I installed Ubuntu 14.04 and GIMP from scratch recently. Just my home folder stayed the same since my home folder has its own partition. PS: Sorry I can't add a comment above since my reputation is <50. PS2: I'm Christoph by the way, no idea why it shows another name beside this comment.

Comment: You appear to have accidentally created two accounts. You should use the [contact form](https://superuser.com/contact) to have your accounts merged. You'll then be able to edit this question.

Comment: There is nothing in GIMP by default that would save an image periodically (many people wish for that, actually). So the increase in 10MB per second has to be caused by something else. Did you ever figure out what this was?